# Brouwer fixed points via flow

Tags: differential-equations, differential-topology, fixed-point-theorems

Let $B$ be a closed ball in $n$-dimensional space, let $f$ be a "sufficiently smooth" map from $B$ to $B$, and let $p$ be a point on the boundary of $B$.

It seems to me that something like the Picard–Lindelöf theorem should ensure that there will be a unique maximally defined solution to the differential equation $x'(t) = f(x(t)) - x(t)$ with $x(0) = p$. Is that correct? Must this solution have a limiting value which is a fixed point of $f$? And is there any way to argue for Brouwer's fixed point theorem in general along these lines?

Comment: Picard-Lindelof and its analogues only guarantee the existence of solutions locally.

Comment: @Christian: $f(x) = 2x$ will not be a map from $B$ to $B$, unless the ball $B$ consists solely of the zero point.

Comment: @Christian: With the correction, the differential equation becomes $x'(t) = f(x(t)) - x(t) = -2x(t)$ with $x(0) = p$, which has unique solution $x(t) = e^{-2t}p$. The limiting value of this for large $t$ will be $0$, which is a fixed point of $f$.

Comment: @Vidit: Yes, and also the uniqueness. Thus, any solutions defined on an open interval around 0 are compatible, and there is at least one, so we can join them all together and obtain a (unique) solution defined on a maximum open interval around 0 (not necessarily the entire real line), just as claimed, no?

Comment: @SidharRamesh: Yes, my "examples" were nonsense. In $d=2$, the issues seem roughly those addressed by Poincare-Bendixson and its variants. This seems to indicate that it will probably be tough to make this work in $d>2$.

Comment: Alas, this needn't work even in two dimensions, I realize: Take $B$ to be the complex numbers of at most unit magnitude, and consider $f(x) = (1 + \frac{1}{2}e^{i \pi |x|^2}) x$, which smoothly maps $B$ into itself. The unique fixed point of this is at the origin, but I believe the limiting behavior of the flow starting anywhere on the boundary will be to cycle around the circle of squared radius $1/2$.

Alas. Well, I'll leave this question here and perhaps someone still will have a good story to tell about conditions under which we should expect this approach to work.

Comment: That is a proof of sorts because a periodic orbit contains a fixed point in its interior (this is easy to prove), so finding a periodic orbit is enough.

Comment: In fact, $d=2$ is immediate from PB: the open disk is invariant, so we obtain a fixed point or a periodic orbit, which then also implies existence of a fixed point.

Comment: For what it's worth, the Hirsch/Kellog-style proof of the Brouwer fixed point theorem turns out to be along the lines I was ultimately hoping for (but, of course, different enough from what I asked about to actually work).